# why spring security makes spring mvc 's postmapping controllder do not work

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

when I config spring security like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider(){
        MyAuthenticationProvider provider = new MyAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

and then I config my controller like this

```
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginPage(){
        System.out.println("GetMapping");
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public void authUser(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String password){
//      just for testing
        System.out.println("PostMapping");
    }
```

and then I visit my login page and enter my username and password, but the console doesn't print `"PostMapping"`, which means the program doesn't go into my method `"authUser"` with `@PostMapping`.

Though my program runs successfully, but it makes me quite confuse.I suppose spring security doing some work automatically, but now I have no idea where to add my Authentications to the SecurityContextHolder.

I hope somebody can help and thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Normally, POST mappings are filtered by CSRFfilters. Although it is not recommended in the production environment, you can disable CSRF filter simply using for learning cases:

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
    .and().logout()
    .and().csrf().disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

It has done by `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, and the default processing path is `Post /login`, and the `Authentication` already exist in `SecurityContextHolder`, you can get it in controller.

If you want to disable form login, change to this.

```
http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
    .formLogin().disable();
```

Comment: thx,what if i want to delete UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and do the job by myself,so how to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: You see,i can't enter my `authUser()`,because it didn't print "PostMapping" in the consoler. So i can do works like authenticating by message or identify code etc.