# Manual Spring security implementation with a call from angular and password encoded

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am sorry in advance for my bad english..

I am working with Spring boot, Spring Security module and Angular. I have a custom database too.

I changed all my project architecture. Before, I had thymeleaf call in my HTML with a login form : **th:action="@/login"**. Now, I removed thymeleaf, so I implemented a simple form with AngularJS.

What I want to do is :

- Click on button in my HTML page **OK**
- Call an angular function **OK**
- Do a POST Request with username and password as parameter **OK**
- Call a Java controller with @RequestMapping(value="/login" method=RequestMethod.POST) annotation **OK**
- Call my configAuthentication() that is in **SecurityConfig.java**.

Before, when I used thymeleaf, this function was automatically called by interception of the request. But now I need to call it manually. How can I do that?

I post my part of code here :

**form in my login.html**

```
<form autocomplete="off">
     <label>{{'login.username' | translate}}</label>
     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" ng-change="message = false" ng-model="username" required/>
      <label>{{'login.password' | translate}}</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" ng-change="message = false" ng-model="password" required/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="login()">{{'login.button' | translate}}</button>
 </form>
```

**My angular function in login.js**

```
$scope.login = function(){
        var dataToSend = {
            username : $scope.username,
            password : $scope.password
        }
        $http.post('/login', dataToSend).success(function(){
            alert("ok");
        }).error(function () {
            alert("skdjs");
        })
    }
```

**My java method in my UserController.java (I need to implement this method with your proposition)**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JSONObject login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody User user) {

}
```

I can have easely password and username but I haven't method getAuthorities.
I have a crypted password as you can see in my **SecurityConfig.java**

For information for logout I have this and it works

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}
```

Finally, my file **SecurityConfig.java** with my method **configAuthentication** not called.

```
package betizy.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("djfkdjfdkfjkd");

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select use_username, use_password, use_enabled from use_user where use_username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select use_username, usr_role from usr_user_role, use_user where use_id = usr_use_id and use_username=?");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers(   "/",
                            "/**",
                            "/user/activate",
                            "/user/activate/**",
                            "/user/create",
                            "/user/register",
                            "/webjars/**",
                            "/templates/**",
                            "/static/**",
                            "/favicon.ico"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
}
```

Thank you a lot for your help !

**PS : I read Spring security ang Angular tutorial but I would like use my method described ahead**

**EDIT**

I am using Spring boot and my application.properties is :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/betizy
spring.datasource.username =  root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And that's all for my Spring Security configuration

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373326/why-spring-security-makes-spring-mvc-s-postmapping-controllder-do-not-work/41373570#41373570

Comment: I don't see why? My problem is that I need a way to link my UserController.java and my method in SecurityConfig.java. @PostMaping is it a solution?

Comment: I think it isn't, it's the reason why I think it's not a duplicate. In addition I don't understand very well his problem in the linked topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager

```
@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JSONObject login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody User user) {

    //does the authentication
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword()
            )
    );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    //just an example of return - you could easily just return the 200 code or smth
    return Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("firstName", user.getFirstName())
            .add("lastName", user.getLastName())
            .add("status", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Hope it helps.